# cannot Autofilter a date column by using an expression

Tags: excel, vba

I am a beginner in VBA. I am automating an excel sheet's date column to count how many dates are between start date and end date.

I have coded like below.

```
F11 = Application.GetOpenFilename("Copy of CES-Product Backlog (*.xlsm*), *.xlsm*")
  If (F11 <> vbNullString) Then
    If (F11 <> "False") Then
      f_name1 = F11
    End If
  End If
  If (f_name1 = "") Then
    MsgBox "The Product Backlog file must be specified."
    Exit Sub
  End If

Set wb1 = Excel.Workbooks.Open(f_name1)
Set sht1 = wb1.Sheets("Product Backlog")

Set wb3 = ThisWorkbook
Set sht3 = wb3.Sheets("check")
With sht3
StartDate = sht3.Range("J3").Value
If IsDate(StartDate) = True Then
MsgBox ("The following string is a valid date expression")
Else
'if its not a date expression show a message box
MsgBox ("The following string is not a valid date expression")

End If

EndDate = sht3.Range("J4").Value

Debug.Print EndDate

End With

wb1.Activate
sht1.Activate
    sht1.Columns("O:O").Select
    wb1.Worksheets("Product Backlog").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    wb1.Worksheets("Product Backlog").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "O1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With wb1.Worksheets("Product Backlog").Sort
        .SetRange Range("O1:O3437")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply

    End With
    'sht1.Columns("X:X").Select
    sht1.Range("$A$1:$X$3432").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:= _
        ">=StartDate", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=EndDate"
```

I want to filter column 15 (date column) of product backlog excel sheet.
In current workbook where I am doing the coding, I have taken two cell (**J3**,**J4**) as start date and end date. when I press button It will consider the start date and end date and will go to product backlog sheet's column 15 and autofilter it with `>=StartDate", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=EndDate"`.

This command is not filtering column 15 and it makes the column blank i mean it filters all the value.
I am not able to find what is the issue with command. Please please anyone have any idea to correct it most welcome.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The dates in Excel are actually stored as sequential serial numbers and then formatted to display the date. January 1, 1900 is serial number 1.

The default date format depends on your computer locale, for the US for example the format is "m/d/yyyy": 5/26/2020. 
If you write 5/26/2020 in one of the cells, Excel will automatically recognize it's type as date, but it will store the actual double value (number) of it 43977. If you change your cell formatting to "General", you can actually see the number.

More info on [MSDN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/datevalue-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252).

Back to your question: You are not passing the actual variable value to the `AutoFilter`. In Excel, Dates are considered as numbers, so you should use the `Double` value of the actual date.

```
sht1.Range("$A$1:$X$3432").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:= _
        ">="&CDbl(StartDate), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<="&CDbl(EndDate)
```

Comment: Thank you Eylm. what is the default format of any date in Excel(string or number). I considered StartDate and and End date as date objects. will that be not enough to hold a string value?. I am confused. Kindly help me.